# Occasional SIGSEGV in NSArray binding

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin

I have the following property that I am binding:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSArray* activeTasks;
```

That I bind with the following code:

```
[Export("activeTasks", ArgumentSemantic.Retain)]
NSDictionary[] ActiveTasks { get; }
```

I use this property very often. Nevertheless, once every thousand of accesses, I get a SIGSEGV on get_activeTasks (the binding of the selector). I wonder what I am doing wrong and why this only happens very rarely instead of systematically.

```
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00024, 0xffffffff>
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.InitializeObject (bool) [0x00062] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/Foundation/NSObject.cs:136
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject..ctor (intptr,bool) [0x0000d] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/Foundation/NSObject.cs:62
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject..ctor (intptr) <IL 0x00003, 0x0002b>
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary..ctor (intptr) <IL 0x00002, 0x00027>
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSMutableDictionary..ctor (intptr) <IL 0x00002, 0x00027>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___intptr (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00054, 0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) <IL 0x00030, 0xffffffff>
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) [0x00109] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:536
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:551
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo,object[]) [0x00174] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:299
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type,object[],object[]) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:234
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type,object[]) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Activator.cs:229
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject (intptr,intptr) [0x0000d] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:210
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject (intptr) [0x0001f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:259
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSArray.ArrayFromHandle<T> (intptr) [0x0003a] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/Foundation/NSArray.cs:172
  at TouchDBBinding.CouchServer.get_ActiveTasks () <IL 0x0001b, 0x00073>
```

EDIT:

Here is an update stack trace using the new Framework, I don't know if it could help out more:

Stacktrace:

```
 at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.monotouch_create_managed_ref (intptr,intptr,bool) <IL 0x0002d, 0xffffffff>
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.CreateManagedRef (bool) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/Foundation/NSObject.cs:93
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.InitializeObject (bool) [0x000cc] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/Foundation/NSObject.cs:88
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject..ctor (intptr,bool) [0x0000d] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/Foundation/NSObject2.cs:85
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject..ctor (intptr) <IL 0x00003, 0x0002b>
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSDictionary..ctor (intptr) <IL 0x00002, 0x00027>
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSMutableDictionary..ctor (intptr) <IL 0x00002, 0x00027>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___intptr (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00054, 0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) <IL 0x00030, 0xffffffff>
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) [0x00109] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:530
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:545
  at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (object[]) [0x0000e] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/ConstructorInfo.cs:62
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject (intptr,intptr) [0x00051] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:269
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject (intptr) [0x0001f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:328
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSArray.ArrayFromHandle<T> (intptr) [0x00044] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/Foundation/NSArray.cs:188
  at TouchDBBinding.CouchServer.get_ActiveTasks () <IL 0x0001b, 0x00073>
```

Is it possible that there is something in the inner workings of MonoTouch that can be a problem when an NSArray* with retain is bound to an NSDictionary[] and that this said property is null? Or is it possible that it is because it has null content?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace indicates that the crash happens when MonoTouch tries to retain one of the elements of the NSArray.

One possible reason is that the particular element has already been freed (or is otherwise corrupted). In particular it is not because the element is null (this case is handled differently).

Comment: How do I need to approach this problem? Is there anything I can do to fix it or is it 100% on the Objective-C side that it is crashing? Random crashes is definitely not something I can live with.

Comment: Try copying the generated code for the ActiveTasks and add extra debug information (print out each pointer in the array for instance, or you could add a manual retain/release call to each object to verify that they don't crash before calling ArrayFromHandle on the array) and if you're using the simulator to reproduce, you can attach gdb to the process to do native debugging.

Comment: Hi Rolf, I do not know if it helps, but I've got a different stack trace this time around (well, for the last two calls). Also, where can I find documentation about where to modify the generated code and how to attach gdb?

Comment: It is the same issue, our own code has just changed somewhat so the stacktrace looks different.

Comment: Where can I find documentation about where to find the generated code? For gdb, I found some guides, I'll try following those.

Comment: Right-click your solution, Display Options -> Show All Files. Then you will find the generated code in one of the previously hidden directories in the binding project (offhand I can't remember exactly which, but there aren't that many to go through).

Comment: Got it! It was in obj->ios->[solution name]. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Hi Rolf, I attached the simulator with GDB and I still get an error in the ArrayFromHandle. https://gist.github.com/airpaulg/025590ee4a3afe406a72

Comment: So, if gdb can't give me information about my native crash, what's the next step for me?

Comment: Try gdb on device as I recommended in another answer. If that doesn't work you'll likely have to debug the x86 assembly code (which is not easy - but I can try to help with that too).

Comment: Okay, I will try it out as soon as I can. Thank you for your quick feedback as always!