# Xamarin.iOS- Debugging native crash in a bound library using GDB

Tags: xamarin.ios, gdb, xamarin

I have a third-party library on which I did bindings and that I built for archiving using XCode. I use it in my C# Xamarin app. Nevertheless, I had a native crash that I have no way of debugging through Xamarin Studio. I tried attaching gdb to the process but I get the following warnings:

```
warning: Could not find object file "/var/folders/mf/w59_1t797k3cfrp7hdmncvt40000gn/T/tmp42fc77da.tmp/libCouchCocoa.a(CouchEmbeddedServer.o)" - no debug information available for "CouchEmbeddedServer.m".


warning: Could not find object file "/var/folders/mf/w59_1t797k3cfrp7hdmncvt40000gn/T/tmp42fc77da.tmp/libCouchCocoa.a(CouchTouchDBDatabase.o)" - no debug information available for "CouchTouchDBDatabase.m".

[...]
```

Then, when the SIGSEGV occurs, I use the bt function and I have no information on what happened in the library. I presume this is related with the warnings.

```
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00000008
[Switching to process 98604 thread 0x28403]
0x0438509b in objc_msgSend ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0438509b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x112924f0 in ?? ()
#2  0x1714fdb0 in ?? ()
#3  0x17555a9c in ?? ()
#4  0x175557f6 in ?? ()
#5  0x17555200 in ?? ()
#6  0x17554c48 in ?? ()
#7  0x17554b4c in ?? ()
#8  0x17554af0 in ?? ()
#9  0x17554aac in ?? ()
#10 0x1718fb1c in ?? ()
#11 0x1718f6dc in ?? ()
#12 0x1718f5d8 in ?? ()
#13 0x0b6c0c8e in ?? ()
#14 0x000a3172 in mono_jit_runtime_invoke (method=0xca60dac, obj=0x10ec7490, params=0xb0974eec, exc=0xb0974ef4) at mini.c:5804
#15 0x0020840e in mono_runtime_invoke (method=0xca60dac, obj=0x10ec7490, params=0xb0974eec, exc=0xb0974ef4) at object.c:2790
#16 0x0020857c in mono_runtime_delegate_invoke (delegate=0x10ec7490, params=0xb0974eec, exc=0xb0974ef4) at object.c:3462
#17 0x002629b4 in mono_async_invoke [inlined] () at :626
#18 0x002629b4 in async_invoke_thread (data=0xc71f870) at threadpool.c:1443
#19 0x00268756 in start_wrapper_internal [inlined] () at :784
#20 0x00268756 in start_wrapper (data=0x1128e680) at threads.c:832
#21 0x0029a69a in thread_start_routine (args=0xfa46204) at wthreads.c:287
#22 0x00245540 in gc_start_thread (arg=0x112922a0) at sgen-gc.c:6280
#23 0x98a89ed9 in _pthread_start ()
#24 0x98a8d6de in thread_start ()
(gdb)
```

How should I build my third-party libraries so that gdb manages to find debug information about them?

**EDIT**: Using p mono_pmip, I managed to get the desymbolicated method name, but is there a way not having to do this and having the debug symbols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have more luck if you use gdb on device.

This can be done using [fruitstrap](https://github.com/rolfbjarne/fruitstrap) (note that fruitstrap is not officially supported by Xamarin - all I can say is that I've been able to use it myself occasionally).

The reason it's harder in the simulator is because we use a JIT there - this means that the mapping between memory addresses and function names / line numbers is only present in-memory, which gdb doesn't understand. When building for device we AOT everything into ARM assembly **and** we create proper debug information that gdb understands.

Comment: So basically, on the device, I would get the same information as mono_pmip or would I have an even deeper stacktrace inside the native library? Because this is related to another question you answered where I didn't manage to get any extra info using gdb (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957609/occasional-sigsegv-in-nsarray-binding/15958976#comment23228767_15958976)

Comment: You would get the same information as mono_pmip (without having to use mono_pmip) - and in addition gdb will be able to inspect local variables and show the C# code.

Comment: Currently, mono_pmip was able to desymbolicate some of my stack trace, but when it comes to desymbolicating the native part of the stack trace, it is not succeeding. It must have to do with the debug information warnings. I will try fruitstrap like you suggested, thanks Rolf!

Comment: mono_pmip is only able to symbolicate managed frames. gdb should be able to symbolicate the native frames (which it did in the stack trace you've posted in this question).

Comment: I tried fruistrap and when I start debugging, I get the following error (I have no idea what a XMCustomView is): https://gist.github.com/airpaulg/d6a93b5e2f96d8f3f581

Comment: My guess is that it's your third-party library. Can you get a stack trace?

Comment: XMCustomView is a demo view written in the Monotouch Samples from my understanding. But now, I can't even get the same error again, it simply crashes with no usable trace: https://gist.github.com/airpaulg/26976027640e55f821fa

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29562/discussion-between-rolf-bjarne-kvinge-and-airpaulg)

Comment: This is how I start my app (it starts with the correct app icon, so I don't think it runs some kind of demo program): https://gist.github.com/airpaulg/2bb65a568529d9951cb5